# WebMatrix 3 does not support IIS Express 10

Tags: iis-express, windows-10, visual-studio-2015, webmatrix-3

I am facing a problem while trying to install `WebMatrix 3` over `Windows 10` after installing `Visual Studio 2015` (IIS Express 10) due to the below mentioned error.

Although it worth mention that I tried to install the older version of `IIS` on `Windows 10`; but it failed due to a newer version already installed (`IIS Express 10`).

Can you please specify what type of logs is needed to investigate the problem, and how can I overcome this message (screenshots in the below url).

URL: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=b0a996d2349d8f9b!275&authkey=!AMRzIKq3jhFPdho&ithint=folder%2c

Error 1:

> This version of Microsoft WebMatrix requires IIS 7.5 Express or IIS
>   8.0 Express to be installed. Please install it and then rerun the setup.

Error 2:

> `WebMatrix 3` does not support IIS Express 10. You will not be able to
>   run `WebMatrix 3` on the same machine with any version of Visual
>   Studio 2015 that includes `IIS Express 10`.

Comment: It is obviously by design.

Answer (score 2):

You can download msi package of WebMatrix from Installation step and install without web platform installer.
But after that I've got another error that WebMatrix could not find Web Platform Installer

**UPD** I've reinstalled Web Platform Installer and now WebMatrix works fine on Windows 10 with IIS 10!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried IISExpress 7 or 8 here?
Looks like at this time it does not support IISExpress10 on windows10.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: If windows 10 64 bit used with IISexpress 32bit then there will be issue. For safer side downgrading IISExpress will work for WebMatrix, though i have not personally used it, just a suggestion.